# Plot text block outside of a plot in R

Tags: r, text, plot, alignment

I want to put a longer text next to a plot but I have problems with the formatting. This is the code for the actual plot:

```
percentile.plot <- function(value = 3, rev = FALSE,
                        col.fade = c("snow2","snow1", "snow"),
                        box.lwd = 3, box.col="snow4", point.col= "black"){
 x <-c(1:5)
 y <- rep(1, 5)
 colfunc <- colorRampPalette(col.fade)
 if(rev){colors <- rev(colfunc(2000))} else { colors <- colfunc(2000) }
 segm <- seq(0, 5, by = 0.005)

par(mar = c(0, 10, 0, 10))
plot(x, y, type = "n", bty="n", axes=F, ylab="", xlab="", 
   xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,1), asp=1,
   xaxs ="i", yaxs = "i")
 segments(x0 = segm, y0 = 0, y1=1, x1 = segm, col= colors, lty=1.2)

segments(x0 = c(0:5), y0 = 0, y1=1, x1 = c(0:5), col= box.col, lwd=box.lwd)
segments(x0 = 0, y0 = c(0:1), y1=c(0:1), x1 = 5, col= box.col, lwd=box.lwd)

if (value >= .99) {value <- .99}
if (value < .01) {value <- .01}
value.trans <- value*5
points(x = value.trans, y = 0.5, pch=4, lwd=3, cex=1.3, col=point.col)

}

percentile.plot(0.9)
```

Now I would like to put text blocks left and right to the plot, which could look like this:

```
text_left <- "I would like to put a text next to my graph \n
            but unfortunately I cannot get the formatting \n
            right. Either my margins are to big to knit my \n
            plot into an html or the text is not aligned \n
            as I want it to be. I am sure there is an easy \n
            solution but I haven’t found one yet." 

text_right <- "I would like to put a text next to my graph \n
            but unfortunately I cannot get the formatting \n
            right. Either my margins are to big to knit my \n
            plot into an html or the text is not aligned \n
            as I want it to be. I am sure there is an easy \n
            solution but I haven’t found one yet."
```

I tried the following:

```
par(lheight = 0.5)
mtext(text_left, las = 1, side = 2, outer = TRUE, adj = 0, line= 5, cex = .8) 
mtext(text_right, las = 1, side = 4, outer = TRUE, adj = 0, line= -8, cex = .8)
```

Which results in:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUruT.jpg)

What I would like is a text block left of the plot, which is aligned on the left and the other on the right of the plot, also aligned on the left. The texts are supposed to be a description of each end of the plot I computed.

Further I tried this on different computers (13'' and 27'') and had to change the margin sizes to get the same result. Is there a better way to add text to the plot? Plus the actual plot should be bigger than it it in the picture but I am unable to do this properly.

Comment: If you want each text block to be comparable in size to the plot, I would recommend using `layout` or `par(mfrow(c(1, 3))` and using different plotting areas for each piece of text and your plot

Comment: Agreed. You may wanna remove the `par` inside your function and try something like `library(gplots);par(mar = rep(0,4));layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3), nrow = 1));textplot(text_left, "right", "center");percentile.plot(0.9);textplot(text_left, "left", "center")`.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be easier with grid graphics

```
percentileGrob <- function(value = 3, ...){
  x <-c(1:5)
  y <- rep(1, 5)
  g1 <- rasterGrob(t(colorRampPalette(blues9)(100)), width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))
  h <- 1/5
  g2 <- rectGrob(x=seq(h/2, 1-h/2, by=h), width=h, gp=gpar(fill=NA))
  g3 <- pointsGrob(seq(h/2, 1-h/2, by=h)[5],0.5, pch=4, gp=gpar(lwd=4))
  grobTree(g1, g2, g3,vp=viewport(width=unit(1,"snpc"), height=unit(1/5,"snpc")))
}

text_left <- "I would like to put a text next to my graph but unfortunately I cannot get the formatting right. Either my margins are to big to knit my plot into an html or the text is not aligned as I want it to be. I am sure there is an easy solution but I haven’t found one yet." 

library(gridExtra)

tl <- textGrob(paste(strwrap(text_left, 50), collapse="\n"), hjust=0, x=0)
tr <- textGrob(paste(strwrap(text_left, 50), collapse="\n"), hjust=0, x=0)
grid.arrange(tl, percentileGrob(), tr, widths=unit.c(grobWidth(tl), unit(1,"npc") - grobWidth(tl) - grobWidth(tr), grobWidth(tr)))
```

[image]